# Running time of programs

Tags: algorithm

I have a question for the running time following programs:
Problem 1:

```
a = 0
for i = 1 to n:
    if i is odd:
        for j = 1 to i:
            a = a + j
```

Problem 2:

```
k = n
while k >= 1:
    k = k / 2
```

What is the running time of these two problems using big O and big Theta?

For the first question, the first line is O(1), the outer for loop is O(n). I am a bit confused by the inner for loop since it is related to j. What I think is when n is large odd number then it will be O(n^2) because of the nested loop.

For the second question, I think it will take n/2 times for k to be smaller than 1. but not sure whether it is O(n) or big theta of n.

Comment: What do you think it is, and why? Where are you having problems in your analysis? *What have you done so far?*

Comment: @John Coleman Not really. I just want to make sure whether my answer is correct or not. For the first problem, the outer loop is O(n) while the inner loop is related to j but not n. I thought it would be O(n^2) but not sure. For the second problem, my answer is big theta of n since it will take n/2 times to iterate the loop.

Comment: You could always incorporate your thoughts into a focused question which includes the actual code rather than giving a link to an image of code and asking for an answer with no evidence of work on your part. Stack Overflow isn't an oracle.

Comment: Your edit helps -- if you post code rather than give links I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions and I will edit the question again. This is my first question on StackOverflow so I didn't do it in a proper way.

Comment: For the first question, a visualization can help to understand the problem. Draw a row of blocks for each pass through the outer loop, where each block represents a pass through the inner loop. You'll find a shape whose area you can calculate in terms of *n*. For the second question, write the times, in terms of *n*, for each pass through the loop. You'll find a mathematical series that converges.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You seem to have a good attitude. A lot of students (which may or may not describe you) try to use Stack Overflow as a tool for doing homework, which tends to elicit negative reactions from the community. On the other hand, asking for more focused help in a way that shows effort on the student's part is okay.

Answer (score 0):

You analysis of the first problem is essentially correct. A key point ingredient is the classic identity

```
1 + 3 + 5 + ... + (2k-1) = k^2
```

in this case `2k-1 = n` (or `n-1`) so the complexity is `O((n/2)^2) = O(n^2)`

For the second problem -- it is a classic divide-and-conquer type problem. The key question is -- how many time do you need to divide `n` by in order to get to 1? This is equivalent to asking how many times you need to multiply 1 by 2 to get to `n`? In other words -- what `k` makes `2^k = n` true? You might want to review what you know about logarithms.

Answer (score 0):

First: you have almost exactly (N x N/2 / 2) operations, so it is O(N^2). Draw a square: you will see you take one triangle (and one case over two).

Second: you have log2 N operations, so it is O(log N).

Answer (score 0):

To understand problem 2, you can simulate an example. And if you write the numbers in the binary base, things should become obvious:

```
100 -> 1100100
 50 ->  110010
 25 ->   11001
 12 ->    1100
  6 ->     110
  3 ->      11
  1 ->       1
```